How to balance PCR template amounts between high and low gene copy targets?
In eukaryotic DNA metabarcoding, whether you use a mitochondrial (e.g. COI, 12S, 16S) or a nuclear (e.g. 18S) marker gene will affect your yield for different reasons. Often it is recommended to use a multi-locus approach if possible – we use COI and 18S. But something struck me while I was PCR amplifying these libraries; We use the same amount of template DNA for COI and 18S, even though the number of gene copies in a given amount of DNA extract is hardly the same for them. Even with mitochondria only containing one gene copy each, per cell they still outnumber any nuclear gene, AFAIK. By how much is the question? What is a good target, if you want to have comparable amounts of template DNA for your PCR reactions? I've read that nuclear rDNA repeats can range from a handful to several hundred, and the number of mitochondria per cell can also vary a lot. Are there any guidelines out there?

How many cycles do you amplify for? Do you get amplification from each reaction? Think about the theoretical amplification of DNA in a PCR and how the number of cycles plays into amplification of rare targets.

What's the intended application? Are you trying to determine [a quantity of starting DNA] based on [a measure of sequences/DNA produced]? Or are you just trying to see if your target is present in the sample?

@Darlingtonia: Just standard procedure metabarcoding, trying to get a good representation of the overall community composition. We would just like to reduce bias introduced by varying template concentrations between marker genes. Ideally optimize the template concentration.

@bob1: We amplify 18S in 30 cycles, and COI in 31 cycles with a touchdown profile. Including an indexing PCR following that, that's quite a few cycles. So I basically always get a gel band from our PCRs based on 2 µl gDNA template, and it's always stronger for COI than for 18S, even with double the input amount for 18S.

@Joel In that case you might either have double the number of copies of COI than 18S in samples, or the efficiencies of the  two PCRs are different, or one is just a larger product, and therefore brighter as it incorporates more stain. You could put them on a qPCR machine and determine the efficiencies to see. PCR based approaches will always have some bias, you would need native barcoding to not I think.

@bob1: Native barcoding? Do you mean sequencing everything?

@Joel Yes - only works well if you are doing things like MinIon.
